# app engine cron job with firebase: publish hourly tick not running in the same period every day

Tags: google-app-engine, firebase, cron, google-cloud-platform

I followed the instructions of the [App Engine Cron with Google Cloud Functions for Firebase](https://github.com/firebase/functions-cron) repo/tutorial and have the hourly-tick scheduled.

It's working, except between 3am and 9am (UTC+2).

In this period, it's being called every minute, but not running properly a single time. I've had this for a couple of days now, it was the same right from the setup and the same every day.

[cron not working between 3am and 9am](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KihuN.png)

I did not change anything, so my cron.yaml for the hourly-tick looks like this:

```
cron:
- description: Push a "tick" onto pubsub every hour
  url: /publish/hourly-tick
  schedule: every 1 hours
```

Did anybody encounter this, or any ideas on why this could be happening?

Cheers

Comment: It seems to me that the problem is more likely to be in the App Engine part than in your cron configuration. That 503 response means that the server is unavailable - is it possible that you've configured App Engine to not run during that period?   Also, the response size is significantly different for an unsuccessful request - it would be worth inspecting that (and adding it to this question).

Comment: Are you maybe running up against a quota if you're not on a payment plan that allows you unlimited execution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was indeed running up against quota, thanks for pointing that out. 
It did not even cross my mind that this could happen with such a basic job. (:

After bit of digging around this is what happened:

1. I did setup a billing account, however, it was not linked to my project.
2. As mentioned in the docs the free quota for backend instances is 9 hours per day.
3. So basically I think the 9 hours ran out every day and gave me a 503 until my quotas were reset.

Thanks guys for the comments and pointing me in the right direction.